React-Native Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open
I'm trying to develop a React-Native project. When I'm making a Patch request, I'm getting this Error.

LOG  [SyntaxError: JSON Parse error: Unexpected end of input]
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\root\react-native\packages\react-native\ReactAndroid\hermes-engine.cxx\Release\e4t6q3ku\x86_64\lib\InternalBytecode\InternalBytecode.js'
at Object.openSync (node:fs:601:3)
at Object.readFileSync (node:fs:469:35)
at getCodeFrame (C:\Users\fiyle\StudioProjects\nurse-scheduling-mobile\nurse_scheduling\node_modules\metro\src\Server.js:868:18)
at Server._symbolicate (C:\Users\fiyle\StudioProjects\nurse-scheduling-mobile\nurse_scheduling\node_modules\metro\src\Server.js:945:22)
at Object.readFileSync (node:fs:469:35)
at getCodeFrame (C:\Users\fiyle\StudioProjects\nurse-scheduling-mobile\nurse_scheduling\node_modules\metro\src\Server.js:868:18)
at Server._symbolicate (C:\Users\fiyle\StudioProjects\nurse-scheduling-mobile\nurse_scheduling\node_modules\metro\src\Server.js:945:22)
at async Server._processRequest (C:\Users\fiyle\StudioProjects\nurse-scheduling-mobile\nurse_scheduling\node_modules\metro\src\Server.js:394:7) {
errno: -4058,
syscall: 'open',
code: 'ENOENT',
path: 'C:\root\react-native\packages\react-native\ReactAndroid\hermes-engine\.cxx\Release\e4t6q3ku\x86_64\lib\InternalBytecode\InternalBytecode.js'
}

Here is my codes. Thank
export async function patchFetch(url: string, payload: any, credentials?: string | 
null) {
const headers: { [key: string]: string } = {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
};

if (credentials) {
    headers['Authorization'] = `Basic ${credentials}`;
}

const requestOptions = await fetch(url, {
    method: 'PATCH',
    headers: headers,
    body: JSON.stringify(payload),
});

const response = await requestOptions.json();
if (requestOptions.status === 200) {
    return response;
} else if (requestOptions.status === 400) {
    throw new Error("Bad Request");
} else if (requestOptions.status === 401) {
    throw new Error("Unauthorized");
} else if (requestOptions.status === 403) {
    throw new Error("Forbidden");
} else {
    throw new Error("Something went wrong");
}}


export const swapShifts = async (id:string,credentials:string) => {
const url = `${BASE_URL}/api/exchange-shift-requests/${id}/accept`;
return await patchFetch(url,{},credentials);}

    const acceptShift = () => {
    if (selectedShift) {
         swapShifts(selectedShift.id, credentials).then(() => {
                setModalVisible(false);
                setSelectedShift(null)
             }
         )
    }}


You should log url and see if it's correct, since I suspect this has to do with a malformed url

@Asleepace there is no problem on url. It updates the entry.

Ah I just noticed the issue is with parsing the response JSON, I would remove the .json() line and inspect the response to make sure it is valid JSON.

Thanks a lot. I fixed the problem with your solution.
